Browse a web page through SSH? (Need to access router web interface remotely, but only have SSH access to a different device on LAN)
I need to remotely open a port on a router (remote web access is off).
I have SSH access to a Raspberry PI (Debian) that is on the same LAN as the router.
Is there some way I can do that remotely from my Windows PC, through the SSH? I can only find how to do it through linux.

You need to create a proxy path - with ssh it's a straightforward command (shown in the answer posted while writing this) and with PuTTY it's equally straightforward:
Connection → SSH → Tunnels → Specify source port and desintation address and port → Access site via https://localhost:<source_port> || https://127.0.0.1:<source_port>

I can't believe how easy that was with Putty! Thanks a lot!

Sometimes the router web interface doesn't work over an SSH tunnel (in case it loads resources from a hardcoded IP). In this case, you can run a proxy like this:
ssh user@host -D 8080

Then you go into your browser settings and set a proxy:

Type: SOCKS5
Host: localhost
Port: 8080

From man ssh:
       -D [bind_address:]port
               Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.  This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the  local  side,  op‐
               tionally  bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over the secure chan‐
               nel, and the application protocol is then used to determine where to connect to from the remote machine.  Currently  the  SOCKS4  and  SOCKS5
               protocols  are  supported, and ssh will act as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward privileged ports.  Dynamic port forwardings can also be
               specified in the configuration file.

               IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing the address in square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged ports.   By  default,
               the local port is bound in accordance with the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may be used to bind the connection to
               a specific address.  The bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or
               ‘*’ indicates that the port should be available from all interfaces.


You can use a SSH tunnel to access it, so for a machine with IP 192.168.0.254 on port 80 within the same LAN as the SSH server:


# ssh <user>@<host> -L <local_port>:<distant_host>:<distant_port>
  ssh user@host -L 8080:192.168.0.254:80


Access via: http://localhost:8080

Some routers check the hostname, so if unable to connect using localhost, replace with 127.0.0.1




When using code fences [three backticks], the fence has to be on it's own line, content on next line(s), closing code fence on it's own line (when putting code fences on the same line as content, it's treated as monospaced code instead of a code box)

Thanks! I managed to access the login page using Putty as described by @JW0914,
but unfortunately I'm unable to login. I suspect that after submitting user/pass I'm possibly redirected to a HTTPS site? I don't know what happens, but URL changes to http://localhost:8080/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm?Save=Save and then after a few seconds browser error 10.0.0.100 took too long to respond.
I tried adding port 443, and use https, but I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, I don't think the login page works with https?

The mention of 10.0.0.100 in the error is interesting. If that's the IP of your router, I think what's happening is that it has hardcoded references to its own IP in the page you're trying to load, which are bypassing your port forward. (E.g. instead of having a redirect to "/somenewpage", which would keep the IP the same and go through your tunnel, it has a redirect to "http://10.0.0.100/somenewpage", which tries to go around it. This is a valid but irritating choice for them to make.) If this is what's happening, I suggest you try the SOCKS proxy option from another answer (using ssh -D.)

Slightly hacky alternate solution, but its saved me a few times(in other situations) and its worth considering as an alternative. YMMV, and its a little crunchy - but you run a browser that's usable over SSH on the pi. I'm running the binary versions not the docker container.
Its a simple download and unzip, I vaguely recall there was a prerequisite it needed, and once you're done you can just remove it.
Running it is as simple as ./carbonyl  - there may be a prompt asking you to run it with a argument for no sandbox on some versions of linux. This appears permissions related, potentially due to apparmor. You can find steps to work around that in my question here
In theory you can use w3m in some cases, but carbonyl has much better support for the modern web.
I need to dig up the password for my router, and I can't promise to how usable it'll be but I've gotten as far as the login page for it


This is amazing, it worked! I actually tried a different browser, and it didn't work (login button was not showing) and I assumed a text browser wouldn't work because of the crappy frame/javascript router management sites.

It's not a text browser exactly. It's a 'full' browser that has a text/cursesish interface. It's very nice for things like this
